# How to resize OR scale icon inside Button in xml android

Tags: android, xml

i have this simple code of xml , how to resize image to large size or small size inside  button , i need to change it just using xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="some text"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'large size' or 'small size' inside ? Maybe add a small drawing ?

Comment: i mean i want to make image look more small , in other words i want to change size of image like width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways:

1) Use different drawables size, like Agustin Sovoplas suggested.

2) Create horizontal LinearLayout with 2 views there - View with your image set as background and TextView with the corresponding text. After that set OnClickListener for this LinearLayout and process it like a regular button.

Comment: this is what i looking for the second way, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

         <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:text="some text" 
                    android:paddingRight="28dp"          
                   />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg.png"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"  
                    android:marginRight="8dp"                      
                   />
         </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this make button above the image, and not this way that i mean how to put icon beside the text in button tag look at this link  http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html there is "button_icon" how to resize this "button_icon" ??

Comment: Just add 50dp padding to your button text

Comment: i did android:drawablePadding="50dp", this doesn't resize icon, this make 50dp space around icon and push the text

Comment: If you really want to customize the drawable size, you should follow the way i suggested. The default implimentation of "android:drawableLeft" does not provide resizing cabability as you wish

Comment: your suggestion not work like i want , button appear above the image , but thanks for your help ,i found the answer  make linear layout with text and image this work fine and appearance same button :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Draw 9-patch to achieve this: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: look at this link http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html there is "button_icon" how to resize this "button_icon" using xml ??

Comment: Use different drawables size for each density. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html